# Jquery datatables filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a datefilter for datatables using a calendar image and it works great.
But when I clear the date it does not show all dates.

How can i make a button to show all dates which would clear the date filter?

Any help/advice on this would be great, thank you in advance.

```
// The plugin function for adding a new filtering routine
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex){
            var dateStart = parseDateValue($("#dateStart").val());
            // aData represents the table structure as an array of columns, so the script access the date value 
            // in the first column of the table via aData[0]
            var evalDate= parseDateValue(aData[3]);

            if (evalDate == dateStart ) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        });

// Function for converting a mm/dd/yyyy date value into a numeric string for comparison (example 08/12/2010 becomes 20100812
function parseDateValue(rawDate) {
    var dateArray= rawDate.split("/");
    var parsedDate= dateArray[1] + dateArray[0] + dateArray[3];
    return parsedDate;
}



$(function() {
    // Implements the dataTables plugin on the HTML table
    var $oTable= $("#example").dataTable( {
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="200">200</option></select>'
        },
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { "sType": "date" }
        ]                   
        }); 


    // The dataTables plugin creates the filtering and pagination controls for the table dynamically, so these 
    // lines will clone the date range controls currently hidden in the baseDateControl div and append them to 
    // the feedbackTable_filter block created by dataTables
    $dateControls= $("#baseDateControl").children("div").clone();
    $("#feedbackTable_filter").prepend($dateControls);

    // Implements the jQuery UI Datepicker widget on the date controls
    $('.datepicker').datepicker(
        {dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy', showOn: 'button', buttonImage: '../images/calendar.jpg', buttonImageOnly: true}
    );      

    // Create event listeners that will filter the table whenever the user types in either date range box or
    // changes the value of either box using the Datepicker pop-up calendar
    $("#dateStart").keyup ( function() { $oTable.fnDraw(); } );
    $("#dateStart").change( function() { $oTable.fnDraw(); } );

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, have you tried:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex){
            var dateStart = parseDateValue($("#dateStart").val());
            //if filter is empty return everything
            if(dateStart === ''){
                return true;
            }
            // aData represents the table structure as an array of columns, so the script access the date value 
            // in the first column of the table via aData[0]
            var evalDate= parseDateValue(aData[3]);

            if (evalDate == dateStart ) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        });
```

if this doesn't work can you post an example on jsfiddle?

EDIT - ok the problem was with `parseDateValue()` which was expecting a date create with `/`. Since you want an exact match, you can omit `parseDateValue()`

```
// The plugin function for adding a new filtering routine
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex){
        var dateStart = $("#dateStart").val();
        //if filter is empty return everything
        if(dateStart === ''){
            return true;
        }
        // aData represents the table structure as an array of columns, so the script access the date value
        // in the first column of the table via aData[0]
        var evalDate= aData[3];

        if (evalDate == dateStart ) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    });
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/eMZtV/1/

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, i did try that before but did not work. Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eMZtV/

Comment: brilliant works like a charm, thank you. How can i get it to clear the date when i type in the search box? Also can i have an image to say show all which would clear the date box

Comment: thank you, although it does not update the dable on clear input.

Comment: Brilliant all works brilliantly. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: This Answer helped me alot! Thank you @Nicola Peluchetti